# Не полностью считывается HTML страница

Tags: java, json, html, потоки-данных, android

Здравствуйте.
Считываю `html` страницу, точнее `JSON` код, с помощью `Java` (это приложение под `Android`):

```
URL url = new URL(sUrl);
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader( in );
char buffer[] = new char[1024];
String line = "";
while ((bf.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    line += new String(buffer);
}
bf.close(); in .close();
```

Считывает, но не полностью. Пытался через `HttpURLConnection`, `BufferInputStream` (здесь использовал `byte[] buffer` размера 1024), но всегда считывает не полностью.
Пытался считывать по символу, но тогда `Android` выдает ошибку.
Все работает в отдельном потоке (класс, унаследованный от `AsyncTask`).
Что может быть не так?

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться StringBuilder'ом. Мне кажется, что ошибка в line += ...

Comment: Не работает, пытался вместо line+=... использовать: 
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
line.append(buffer);
Все равно не до конца считывает.

Comment: @antoncti, может быть, *сервер* возвращат вам "незаконченный" JSON? Давайте ссылку, я посмотрю и помогу с кодом.

Comment: @antoncti, Вы пробовали сделать вот [так](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6503817)?

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает. Можно вопрос: "Почему не работает просто line+="" или line+= new String(считанная_строка_или_массив_byte[])"? Раньше так считывал в некоторых программах.